# Accessing a sub-document ID after save - mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

When a user is created on my app their details are saved on the MongoDB using mongoose. The `user schema` contains sub-documents and I am trying to access the `_id` if the sub-document after using the `user.save` function.

The schema is below:

```
{
  name: String,
  email: String,
  address: String,
  phone:[
     {landLine: Number,
      mobile: Number}
   ]
}
```

I can access the name, email and address easily like so:

```
console.log(user.name + user.email + user.address)
```

I tried `user.phone._id` but it returns `undefined`. I think because `phone` is an array of objects.

```
 user.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    throw err;
                else {
                    console.log("user ID " + user._id); // SUCCESS!!
                    console.log("user sub-document ID " + user.phone._id); // UNDEFINED!!
                    return (null, user);
                }
            });
```

**How can I access the _id of the sub-document inside the `save` function right after the user is created and saved into mongoDB?**

Comment: In you schema `phone` is not subdocument, so it doesn't have `_id`.

Comment: @AlexanderMac I think the question is not correctly showing the schema. It probably really is `phone: [{ landline: Number, mobile: Number }]`, but it would be nice to get a confirmation of that. And of course it would be `user.phone[0]._id` for the "first" element, but also not clear in context if this is an "initial" save with one array element or adding another one

Comment: @NeilLunn Yeah sorry about the schema you are correct. I will update my question

Comment: Looks like you still are not representing the schema correctly.

Comment: @NeilLunn using `user.phone[0]._id` does work but only for initial save. User can added multiple objects into the phones array later on. Is their anyway of getting the current added/saved sub-document ID.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was getting at and therefore looking for some context in your question. How are you in fact adding additional item(s) to the array? And more to the point, how is the data actually coming in before you actually apply to adding to the array? This gives some context as to the different approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of approaches to getting this information, but personally I prefer the "atomic" modification method using [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

The actual implementation here is helped by mongoose automatically including an `ObjectId` value which is "monotonic" and therefore always increasing in value. So this means that my method for handling this even works with a `$sort` modifier applied to the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/).

For example:

```
// Array of objects to add
var newNumbers = [
  { "landline": 55555555, "mobile": 999999999 },
  { "landline": 44455555, "mobile": 888888888 }
];

User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "email": email },
  { "$push": { "phone": { "$each": newNumbers } } },
  { "new": true },
  function(err,user) {
    // The trick is to sort() on `_id` and just get the
    // last added equal to the length of the input
    var lastIds = user.phone.concat().sort(function(a,b) {
      return a._id > b._id
    }).slice(-newnumbers.length);
  }
)
```

And even if you used a `$sort` modifier:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { "email": email },
  { "$push": { "phone": { "$each": newNumbers, "$sort": { "landline": 1 }  } } },
  { "new": true },
  function(err,user) {
    var lastIds = user.phone.concat().sort(function(a,b) {
      return a._id > b._id
    }).slice(-newnumbers.length);
  }
)
```

That little trick of "sorting" a temporary copy on the `_id` value means that the "newest" items are always at the end. And you just need to take as many off the end as you added in the update.

The arguable point here is that it's actually `mongoose` that is inserting the `_id` values in the first place. So in fact those are being submitted in the request made to the server for each array item.

You "could" get fancy and use "hooks" to record those `ObjectId` values that were actually added to the new array members in the update statement. But it's really just a simple process of returning the last `n` "greatest" `_id` values from the array items anyway, so the more complex approach is not needed.